# Outputing HLS m3u8 TS segment PHP-FPM Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm reading a dynamicly generated m3u8 hls playlist from ffmpeg

basically the file look like

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:3
#EXTINF:11.000000,
2_3.ts
#EXTINF:8.000000,
2_4.ts
#EXTINF:11.000000,
2_5.ts
#EXTINF:11.000000,
2_6.ts
#EXTINF:8.000000,
2_7.ts
#EXTINF:11.000000,
2_8.ts
```

I'm trying to find a way to limit the connection to a single connection.
I have a Table called Connection : it save the Stream ID + User ID + Date_Start & Date_end & status

Once a user started watching the stream it add new Data : Example

```
(StreamID : (2) , userID : (3) , Date_Start : Now() , Date_end : Null , status : ON )
```

once he closed the connection i would like to update the date_end with Now() & status to OFF

Environnement :
Nginx , PHP-FPM & FFmpeg

i'm using `the register_shutdown_function( 'shutdown' )` to write the last update

however the problem is once the playlist is played the shutdown is executed many times duo to the m3u8 contains 6 segments , each few seconds the shutdown is executed many times again (duo the chunk list updated) while i didnt closed yet the connection .

I'm looking a way to handle the playlist as one connection to be keeped , so the function shutdown will be Executed ONLY when client abort the connection and not while the playlist been reloaded

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use a single persistent connection the PHP script will be executed for each playlist request, and,  like you noticed the registered  shutdown function will get called at each run's end.

Instead of updating `Date_end` immediately log the HTTP requests along with the user and stream IDs and periodically calculate the statistics. Eg. if a playlist was not reloaded for `T` time consider it's a new view session.

Also, I don't know how you're keeping track of the user ID but keep in mind that the player software won't likely maintain a session and the information will not be saved across requests. You could add tracking variables in the playlist and segment URLs.

This works only for Live playlists because for VOD the playlist is loaded only once.

If you can use a Web-based player you can hopefully track the user on the client-side via some callbacks.

Comment: Salut aergistral, actually i keep the user id to keep user stats when end & double connection , i dont understand exactly what do you mean by : "if a playlist was not reloaded for T time consider it's a new view session. " i cant find a good way to solve that

Comment: here is an example of output (Type + PID + Time + Segment)  , http://pastebin.com/9mkuNjDz

Comment: If you have multiple concurrent users who request the same playlist at the same time how do you know which one is which? You need a way to track each request/user. If the playlist stops being requested for a time way greater than the `TARGETDURATION` you can assume the session ended and you update the `Date_end` with the time of the last request.

Comment: once a user request i save on a table connection (userID , streamID, date_Start (with time() ) , data_end (Null) , status (ON) ) , and i return the Connection_ID , after next request segment i check if the UserID & StreamID exist , if Yes return that Connection_ID , else Add to table , so via that Connection_ID later i will update the date_end with current time() value and status to OFF , now the issue part is to know that user quitted the stream (mean detect at register_shutdown_function) but how ?

Comment: now let's go with your idea about T time , if you go back to the pastebin i sent you , let's say i quitted at Shutdown: 20707 01:21:22pm (line 29) , the last playlist is also generated at PlayList: 20707 01:21:22pm (line 28) which mean the interval is 0 second ! , so cant figure exactly how i can compare that ? here is another 5min log http://pastebin.com/cvtDHCci

Comment: @Krasic Unfortunately you can't use the shutdown function since the script is executed and exits after each request. What you can do is update the `date_end` on each request and if no request is received for a while you consider the session done and calculate the duration since the last `date_start`.

Comment: after a small modification in code , i got to get the php-fpm user pid to be changed only at playlist change plz look here for new log http://pastebin.com/vazFr3k7 , Type , user Php-fpm pid , time , md5 playlist , as i can see the pid change on playlist change (md5 checksum) , is there a way to keep that pid value unique from the start on that case : 25796 (saved in connection table)  , if we can get to be kept , we can later use shutdown function to check if that pid exist else user exit & date_end update , can it be done somehow via http range ? btw on Vod it work fine.